# JQuery UI Tabs - Custom animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

I need to create animation like this - [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Lewitje/pen/doJRBX)

Using JQuery UI Tabs - [jQuery UI Tabs](https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/)

Problem occur when I need to create animation for container. There is only show/hide option and don't support fx option in newest version. How I can accomplish it?

Main question: can somebody provide codepen/fiddle with custom function animation (so everybody will benefit) like function inside show/hide method? It is possible?.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Variables
  var clickedTab = $(".tabs > .active");
  var tabWrapper = $(".tab__content");
  var activeTab = tabWrapper.find(".active");
  var activeTabHeight = activeTab.outerHeight();

  // Show tab on page load
  activeTab.show();

  // Set height of wrapper on page load
  tabWrapper.height(activeTabHeight);

  $(".tabs > li").on("click", function() {

    // Remove class from active tab
    $(".tabs > li").removeClass("active");

    // Add class active to clicked tab
    $(this).addClass("active");

    // Update clickedTab variable
    clickedTab = $(".tabs .active");

    // fade out active tab
    activeTab.fadeOut(250, function() {

      // Remove active class all tabs
      $(".tab__content > li").removeClass("active");

      // Get index of clicked tab
      var clickedTabIndex = clickedTab.index();

      // Add class active to corresponding tab
      $(".tab__content > li").eq(clickedTabIndex).addClass("active");

      // update new active tab
      activeTab = $(".tab__content > .active");

      // Update variable
      activeTabHeight = activeTab.outerHeight();

      // Animate height of wrapper to new tab height
      tabWrapper.stop().delay(50).animate({
        height: activeTabHeight
      }, 500, function() {

        // Fade in active tab
        activeTab.delay(50).fadeIn(250);

      });
    });
  });

  // Variables
  var colorButton = $(".colors li");

  colorButton.on("click", function() {

    // Remove class from currently active button
    $(".colors > li").removeClass("active-color");

    // Add class active to clicked button
    $(this).addClass("active-color");

    // Get background color of clicked
    var newColor = $(this).attr("data-color");

    // Change background of everything with class .bg-color
    $(".bg-color").css("background-color", newColor);

    // Change color of everything with class .text-color
    $(".text-color").css("color", newColor);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #50555a;
}

.main{
    padding: 100px 20px;
}

nav {
  z-index: 9;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.bg-color {
  background-color: #46a1de;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
.text-color {
  color: #46a1de;
  transition-duration: .5s;
}
footer {
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .33;
  color: white;
}
.wrapper {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.tabs {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(5px);
  transform: translateY(5px);
}
.tabs > li {
  transition-duration: .25s;
  display: table-cell;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 20px 25px 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
.tabs > li:before {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  transition-duration: .25s;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}
.tabs > li:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(70%);
  transform: translateY(70%);
}
.tabs > li.active {
  color: #50555a;
}
.tabs > li.active:before {
  transition-duration: .5s;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  transform: translateY(0);
}
.tab__content {
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.tab__content > li {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
}
.tab__content > li .content__wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 45px 40px 40px 40px;
  background-color: white;
}
.content__wrapper h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.content__wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.colors {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
.colors > li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: .2s;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.colors > li:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
  border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.colors > li.active-color {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-10px);
  transform: scale(1.2) translateY(-10px);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.colors > li:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.colors > li:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #D64A4B;
}
.colors > li:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #8e44ad;
}
.colors > li:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #46a1de;
}
.colors > li:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="bg-color main">
  <nav class="bg-color">Adaptive tabs</nav>

  <section class="wrapper">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="active">Colors</li>
      <li>Favorite movies</li>
      <li>About</li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="tab__content">
      <li class="active">
        <div class="content__wrapper">
          <h2 class="text-color">Pick a color</h2>

          <ul class="colors">
            <li data-color="#2ecc71"></li>
            <li data-color="#D64A4B"></li>
            <li data-color="#8e44ad"></li>
            <li class="active-color" data-color="#46a1de"></li>
            <li data-color="#bdc3c7"></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content__wrapper">
          <h2 class="text-color">Her</h2>

          <img src="http://lewihussey.com/codepen-img/her.jpg">
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content__wrapper">
          <h2 class="text-color">About</h2>

          <p>Created by <a class="text-color" href="http://lewihussey.com" target="_blank">Lewi Hussey</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <footer>By Lewi Hussey</footer>

</div>
```